# Git Jenkins - how to skip git fetch tags in script pipeline declarative?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a problem in my pipelines on Jenkins, when my code is cloned from Bitbucket, it takes a lot of time performing this line:

> git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:team/empresas.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

My pipeline execute this stage:

```
stage('checkout git') {
    steps {
        git branch: branch, credentialsId: 'develop214', url: scmUrl
    }
}
```

Jenkins when perform my stage execute all this tasks:

```
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:fisateam/empresas.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:team/empresas.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:team/empresas.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision f87a5d7586308093e4ab22fbace8c9f817316c29 (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f f87a5d7586308093e4ab22fbace8c9f817316c29
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D develop # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b develop f87a5d7586308093e4ab22fbace8c9f817316c29
Commit message: "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop' into develop"
 > git rev-list --no-walk f87a5d7586308093e4ab22fbace8c9f817316c29 # timeout=10
```

There is any configuration to avoid the execution of "git fetch --tags" programaticaly in pipeline script?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, We found the problem of extreme slow execution pipelines Jenkins, it was triggered because we did some changes in our firewall, it provoked the connection to bitbucket would be too slow only in the segment of servers.